# Ant Build not able to recognize JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, ant, build

I am getting following error while doing build using ANT:

```
rem bug ID 32069: resetting an undefined env variable changes the errorlevel.
if not "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_30\bin\java.exe" == "" set _JAVACMD=
if not "" == "" set ANT_CMD_LINE_ARGS=
```

I understand that ANT is not able to point to JDK. I am starting ANT build via `.bat` file and there I am specifying following

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_30
set ANT_HOME=C:\Softwares\apache-ant-1.8.4
```

If add double quotes to JAVA_HOME value, I get following error:

```
if exist "C:\Softwares\apache-ant-1.8.4\lib\ant.jar" goto checkJava

set _JAVACMD=
Files was unexpected at this time.
if ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_30"" == "" goto noJavaHome
```

Confusing part is if I change ANT_HOME to a previous version (1.6) it works fine.

```
set ANT_HOME=C:\Softwares\Ant
```

Comment: maybe you should use quotes: set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_30"

Comment: It didn't help. I have updated my question

Comment: What is the actual error you see? Unless I'm wrong, you have just included a bit of the batch file you run it with, not the error you see

Comment: Are you sure you are quoting the path correctly?

Comment: Yes sir. As I mentioned if I change the path to Ant 1.6, it works fine.

Comment: I've run into this problem in Ant where there are spaces in the various `_HOME` directories. I always install my JDK and Ant in a directory path without spaces. That is, something like `C:\Java\JDK1.6.0`. You can also see if you can use the old _8.3_ name of the directory. This will be something like `C:\Progra~1` or `C:\Progra~2`. You can use `dir /X` to see these short names.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be related to the 32bit JDK on a 64 bit Windows but I'm not sure about that.

What worked for me was using the old ~ trick which apparently still works. So in your case it should probably be:

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Progra~2\Java\jdk1.6.0_30
set PATH=C:\Progra~2\Java\jdk1.6.0_30\bin;%PATH%
```

Notice that progra~2 maps on my machine to the x86 program files directory. Might be different on yours so you need to check that.