# Setting up dev env for Cordova on Windows: ant does not recognize JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, windows, cordova, ant

I have been trying to set up Cordova on my Windows 7 machine. After hours of troubleshooting I believe I have narrowed the problem down to the configuration of ant, but I'm at a loss as to how to fix it.

When executing `cordova build` from the prompt, under `-compile:` I get:

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\path\to\ant\build.xml:601: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\path\to\ant\build.xml:720: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\path\to\ant\build.xml:734: Unable to find javac compiler;
com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
Perhaps JAVA_HOME_ does not point to the JDK.
It is currently set to "C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_20"
```

Now the frustrating part is that **in my environment variables JAVA_HOME does point to the JDK and not the JRE**. When I run `set JAVA_HOME` I get:

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_20
```

When I run `echo %JAVA_HOME%` I get:

```
C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_20
```

Here are all of my relevant environment variables (I think):

ANT_HOME: C:\ant

JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_20

PATH: C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin;C:\Development\adt-bundle\sdk\platform-tools;C:\Development\adt-bundle\sdk\tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_20\bin;C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin;C:\Users\Casey Ydenberg\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\ant\bin;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;

Any suggestions as to what to try?

Thank you,
Casey

Comment: run `echo %JAVA_HOME%` from the command line. What does it output?

Comment: See edits above. echo %JAVA_HOME% outputs: `C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_20`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this answer: [Ant Build not able to recognize JAVA_HOME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12620467/ant-build-not-able-to-recognize-java-home)

I tried changing JAVA_HOME to

```
C:\Progra~2\Java\jdk1.8.0_20
```

and the JDK part of the PATH to

```
C:\Progra~2\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin.
```

It worked (yay), but I have absolutely no idea why.

Comment: Probably because this path doesn't contain spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Its probably a misconfigured environmental variable. Your error message indicates ANT is trying to use the JRE.

Go to `System Properties > Environment Variables` and make sure there is a system variable for `JAVA_HOME` set to `C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_20`. Verify that that folder is where your jdk is installed. Open a new command prompt and type `echo %JAVA_HOME%` to verify.

Answer (score 0):

I've written an article about installing Cordova on windows here: http://jewelfarazi.me/installing-cordova-with-android-studio-on-windows/

Your can try this, first add environment variable JAVA_HOME:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79
```

And Then add to environment path:

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

So rather adding the whole path you can do similar for ANT_HOME as well and it should work!